# Test if 2 transfer functions are the same in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transfer-function

Suppose that I have two transfer functions (or two matrices of transfer functions in the more general case). How do I test if these are the same (equal)?

```
>> G1 = 1/(s*(s-1));
>> G2 = 1/(s*(s-1));
>> G1 == G2 % won't work..
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test if two of anything are equal:

```
isequal(a,b)
```

Comment: bahaha, test if two anything.  Sweet.